# SMS gateway: receiving from different phone numbers each time

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I am testing out SMS email gateway to send regular texts, but I am receiving them from different phone numbers each time. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What SMS gateway are you using?

Comment: Each phone provider's SMS email gateway. Are there others?